# What atmosphere composition would make my weapon shoot orange plasma?

Tags: space-warfare, colors, plasma

I am planning on painting a Warhammer 40k army that uses **orange plasma** for their energy based weapons, and use that exact same orange plasma for my worldbuilding, and other unrelated works of writing.
I actually don't know that much about what gives plasma a particular color, I guess it depends of the gases used to form it, but what composition would be a good match for a bright yellowish orange plasma ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: A very quick search yields results about what gases glow what colors.

Comment: I'm wondering if this question is maybe a better fit for [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), as the worldbuilding aspect doesn't seem to be of importance to your question.

Comment: Well I also wondering on what material should be in important quantity in the region to back up the production of such plasma

Comment: @CommissarWilhelm well if you used neon, then neon production, if you used helium, then helium production, etc

Comment: @Topcode thanks, I have checked, and I've found two results that are interesting. Sorry for the out of topic post

Comment: If you're asking about what Warhammer 40K fluff makes their plasma specific colors that isn't a question about worldbuilding it's about 40K lore.

Comment: I think my esteemed colleagues may have forgotten to say welcome to worldbuilding, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Comment: I agree with Joachim that Physics stack exchange would be a better resource for this question

Comment: Sea spray, fire a plasma cannon by the ocean and you'll find it produces the most brilliant yellow-orange light! It doesn't take much Sodium (one half of a salt molecule) to really light up a flame or plasma. Take a pin or paperclip, dip one end in salt water and then into a gas flame, viola' orange plume. Just have the battle take place by the sea and bingo, hmm... actual ***marine*** space marines...

Answer (score 3):

[Table](https://chemistry.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Metal-Ion-Flame-Test-Colours.jpg)

from [here](https://chemistry.com.pk/infographics/metal-ion-flame-test-colours/)

Sodium (yellow) and calcium (orange) seems to be the closest fit to your requested color

Every atom has a particular spectral characteristics when it is ionized or heated up. Some molecules are strong enough to survive it as well, but as far as I know atoms dominate.

Metals provide much stronger color than other materials

To look for color and material use 'spectral lines (material)' for search. Only atoms or very simple molecules make sense for this request. If spectral lines are numerous and spread out throughout the spectrum, color will seem more white and less colorful.

Gasses provide significantly weaker color in atmospheric conditions usually. In gas lamps low pressure gas is used - neon, krypton, argon. But so are metal vapors - sodium, mercury. Gas lamps are used for convinience i think, and for particular color they provide.

In normal conditions adding gas like neon to the flame will not make the flame colorful, while metal will.